# UI representation of Server Object

Tags: c#, architecture

I have an application where lots of objects are created and whose property are changing frequently by user. There are various modules in server, and for each module one session is created. Each session consists one clients and one user running the main app. User just interfere with objects and modify its property which current I am using a property grid in windows form to do it. How client will be connected to main app is yet to decide. I am thinking of duplex WCF service. I need two suggestions :

1. How to represent the remote objects on client UI? I was thinking of creating UI items manually on VS form designer and place a mapping XML file, which UI on initialize use the mapping table to get property details of each UI element and modify accordingly. Like a panel in UI will be filled with some color when mapped object's faulted state is true.
2. Since the objects on server is changing frequently, what is the best way to tell the client to update the UI. I was thinking of duplex WCF where if client is registered for particular object, he will be notified the change in object. My question is should we transfer entire object to client or only the updated property along with object Id (wrapped in new type)

   ```
   interface IChange
   {
       string ObjectName { get; set; }
       string PropertyName { get; set; }
       object NewValue { get; set; }
       object OldValue { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Suggest me alternative or better way to achieve my goal

**EDIT**

For now no of objects are not much but it may grow drastically. This application is plugin based, and developer may add thousands of objects + there could be several plugins. Object size I do not expect to be higher than 10-20kB but is not definite. Point is if I send entire object to client (90% of object is useless, only updated property is relevent to the client.), client has to scan all the properties and update UI. But if I send only change to the client, then client knows what to change. Updates to objects could be very frequent, as any change in one property of object, it triggers several changes to other objects (kind of chain reaction), and all changes should be notified. For an example, if I change IsOn property of main switch of my home, all appliances will be triggered to shut down. And all such object changes needs to be notified to client. Once client has notification of each object being shut down, it will display all appliances on UI as not running.

Comment: How often do the objects typically change?

Answer (score 0):

> > My question is should we transfer entire object to client or only the updated property along with object Id (wrapped in new type)?

**Performance**: Depends how big the data objects are, and how many change at anyone time.  For example, if you have 1000 objects and each is 1Mb in size, with 1000 different properties and on average only 1 or 2 minor changes are made then it makes sense to only send across the changes.

- Less network load
- Less memory / processing intensive
- Especially true if you have to de-serialize lots of XML.

**Complexity**: Sometimes it's easier to just blow away anything that's changed and start from scratch; you don't need to worry so much about maintaining object state, handling multiple changes on the same object, etc.

> Since the objects on server is changing frequently, what is the best
>   way to tell the client to update the UI?

Comes back to the number of likely objects, how often they change and where they come from ("*How client will be connected to main app is yet to decide*").  Also depends on how up-to-date the UI needs to be.  If an object changes on the server, and you have 100 clients that need to be updated - how soon do they need to be updated?

Keep in mind that the more frequently and faster things change the more "chatty" your application will be, which will start to kill performance the more boundaries you have to cross (domain, process, server, network...).

**Edit**

So it sounds like the [unit of work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) pattern might help:

- Let all the knock-on changes take effect when a change request comes in.
- Then issue all changes (the deltas not the entire objects) as a single "batch" / collection back to the caller.
- Maybe use some sort of cache if you have lots of clients wanting the new data.